# How do I string 2 queries such that the data from the first call feeds the second call (server side only)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, routes

Basically I want to chain multiple calls from the server to the databse but only with one call from the client... yes i know its suicidal for cost but necessary unfortunately :(

**The groundworks**:
So I am abstracting this to a high level design of my "servers". (Ignore the fact that I have left protocols and firewalls out please... on purpose)
This is what I want to implement to make sure authorizations are almost bullet proof (not authentication):

1)The user makes a call:
(END USER CLIENT)--->(call)-->(server)

2)Server transforms the call to look up a authorizations table with users access:
(EUCLIENT)--->(call)-->(server)(module1: gets auth for user)--> (dbserver)

3)DB server returns the data:
(EUCLIENT)--->(call)-->(server)(module1)<----return---(dbserver)

4)Now another module applies this auth and adds it as a filter on a newwly built query on top of the user query:
(EUCLIENT)--->(call)-->(server)(module2: ==new query==)

5) Finally a module send the finished query to the db sesrver one last time:
(EUCLIENT)--->(call)-->(server)(module3)--call----> (dbserver)

6) DB sends response, server serves response back to user:
-----------------------(server)(module3) <--return----(dbserver)
(EUCLIENT)<---return<--(server)(module4)

**The question**:
Is it possible to query 2 times the db query all with just one call from the client side?(I know this incurs a roundtrip time cost doing 2 calls but I have my reasons :)
finally What verbs do I need to use in module 2 or 3 to do this so the call remains open, is it just a a callback?

thank yuo very much for yout time in advance
Alex

Ive tried chainig middleware but this is very early stages and appreicate any help ... dont want to go down the rabbit hole if its not possible to come back out!

Comment: Yes, doing multiple requests to DB (or maybe even other services) is an everyday thing in any non-trivial app.

Comment: Thank you Sergio, I'll get this up and running then :)